# Getting "Creation of service was not idempotent" with boto3 ECS. Why?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-ecs

I am making a call to `ecs.create_service` like this:

```
createServiceResponse = ecs.create_service(
clientToken='abc123',
cluster=options.cluster,
serviceName=options.service,
desiredCount=1,
taskDefinition='relay:' + str(revision),
role='ecsServiceRole',
loadBalancers=[
    {
        'loadBalancerName': options.elb,
        'containerName': 'relay',
        'containerPort': 8080
    }
]
)
```

Note that the value in clientToken is `abc123` at the moment, but I've tried all sorts of different strings. This document says I need to supply it to ensure idempotency (http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ecs.html) however I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./deploy.py", line 103, in <module>
    'containerPort': 8080
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 301, in _api_call
  return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _make_api_call
   raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred     (InvalidParameterException) when calling the CreateService operation: Creation of service was not idempotent.
```

Why ?

Answer (score 32):

I figured it out.

It was because I was calling `create_service` on an existing service. I should have been calling `update_service` as follows:

```
ecs.update_service(

cluster=options.cluster,
service=options.service,
taskDefinition='relay:' + str(revision),    
desiredCount=1)
```